# Convert Java ResultSet to Spark DataFrame

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-spark, resultset, apache-spark-sql

I use pandas to manipulate data in Python.

I went through Spark's DataFrame and wanted to use this structure for a program that I'm developing in Java.

I have my data in SQL Server, I have the SQL results in [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html). I want to convert this to [DataFrame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#datasets-and-dataframes)

How can I do this conversion? Is there an easier way to convert SQL result directly to DataFrame?

---

EDIT: I tried to connect SQL Server via SparkSession below details

```
   public static SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
           .master("local[*]")
        .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
        .getOrCreate();

    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
    options.put("url", "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<clipped>");
    spark.read().format("jdbc").options(options).load();

    Dataset<Row> sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM HEDE);
```

Now I'm getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Option 'dbtable' not specified` How/where can I specify table?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify table in options:

```
options.put("dbtable", "some_table");
```

or using JDBC method:

```
spark.read().jdbc("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<clipped>", "some_table", properties)
```

where `properties` is `java.util.Properties`.